# HTML Layout with elements that are fixed horizontally and scroll vertically

Tags: html, layout, scroll, fixed

I have an HTML layout that has elements that are fixed horizontally and scroll vertically, and it mostly works, except that it has a scrolling div meaning that drag to refresh does not work on mobile.

It shows a sports draw with results, and has a fixed header, times on the left that scrolls vertically but not horizontallty, and content that scrolls vertically and horizontally.

[Here is a gif of the scrolling in the main app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loIdc.gif)

[Here is a gif of the scrolling in a cutdown sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tisod.gif)

Here is a cutdown sample in a single HTML file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tourney Layout Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/html/favicon.png">    
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: white;">
    <div style="overflow: scroll">
      <div style="background: black; height: 100px; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: 5000;">
        X: Fixed<br/>Y: Fixed
      </div>
      <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <div style="background: darkred; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; height: 400px; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
            X: Fixed<br/>Y: Scroll
          </div>
          <div style="display: flex; margin-left: 100px;">
            <div style="background: red; width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; height: 400px;">
              X: Scroll<br/>Y: Scroll
            </div>
            <div style="background: purple; width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; height: 400px;">
              X: Scroll<br/>Y: Scroll
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: flex;">
          <div style="background: darkblue; width: 100px; min-width: 100px; max-width: 100px; height: 500px; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
            X: Fixed<br/>Y: Scroll
          </div>
          <div style="display: flex; margin-left: 100px;">
            <div style="background: blue; width: 400px; min-width: 400px; max-width: 400px; height: 500px;">
              X: Scroll<br/>Y: Scroll
            </div>
            <div style="background: green; width: 300px; min-width: 300px; max-width: 300px; height: 500px;">
              X: Scroll<br/>Y: Scroll
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
```

Is there a way to achieve the desired result, without the scrolling div, so the scrolling is just handled by the body, and scroll to refresh will work on mobile?